# How do I add references to HTML elements in to my JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

The [Cytoscape.js example shown here](http://js.cytoscape.org/) has this reference in the JSON:

```
 container: document.getElementById('cy'),
```

eg.

```
cytoscape({

  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  elements: [
    { // node n1
      //... snip
    }]
});
```

If I manually create that JSON String, and call cytoscape() on it, it works fine.

However, I've returning a JSON string from a servlet, and on the client side, I need to add the container value.

I've tried:

```
function updateGraph(json) {
    console.log(json);

    pjson = JSON.parse(json);
    pjson["container"] =  document.getElementById('graph-container');
    json = JSON.stringify(pjson);
    console.log(json);

    cytoscape(json);
}
```

But this will show the container element as:

```
"container":{}
```

What's the correct way to add a HTML element reference?

Comment: JSON can only hold plain JS objects, arrays, strings, numbers, booleans and nulls. Element references cannot be represented in JSON. What exactly do you expect it to stringify as? Pass `pjson` to cytoscape, without stringifying, no?

Comment: @Amadan - Then how come the reference works in the original JSON?

Comment: That is not JSON, it is an object literal in JS code. Your `pjson` is an object literal, just what you need.

Comment: @Amadan passing it as the object literal solved it. I'm don't quite understand it though. If JSON can only hold arrays, strings, numbers etc... then how come including the unstringed `document.getElement...` works?

Comment: Because that is not JSON, but object literal. JSON: `'{ "foo": "bar" }'`. JS object: `{ "foo": "bar" }`. Note the quotes - JSON is always a string. Object literal is executable JS code, same as `console.log(7)` and `for (var i = 9; i; i--);` - `document.getElement...` gets executed when the object literal evaluates. `var result = { "sum": 1 + 2 }` is JS code comparable to yours; `'{ "sum": 1 + 2 }'` is a string, and invalid JSON (`'{ "sum": 3 }'` is a valid JSON).

Comment: `cytoscape({ ... })` is invoking cytoscape with an object. You were trying to invoke it with a string, equivalent to `cytoscape("{ ... }")`. I don't know if cytoscape works with both JSON and objects and JSON-parsing if it happens to receive a string, but all examples I saw except yours are using objects, not JSON.

Comment: @Amadan Ok you should post the clarification as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('graph-container');
```

will return a html element embedded within <>. A Javascript Object Notation(JSON) cannot hold such elements, that is it cannot parse such elements. It can only hold arrays, objects of string, boolean, numbers and null.

Answer (score 0):

Only literals can be represented in JSON, and property names are always double-quoted strings, so your exemple:

```
container: document.getElementById('cy'),
```

is not part of a valid JSON object.

A JSON object could contain something like:

```
"container-id": "cy",
```

You would obviously need a post treatment after the JSON.parse to retrieve the DOM element.

Answer (score -1):

As seen in comments, there is a big confusion as to what JSON is. JSON, like XML, is a way of encoding data in a string form. These are valid JSON in context of JavaScript code:

```
'1'
'"quux"'
'[2, 3, 4]'
'{ "foo": ["bar", "baz"] }'
```

In JavaScript code, this is not JSON:

```
1
"quux"
[2, 3, 4]
{ "foo": ["bar", "baz"] }
```

The first one is an integer, the second one is a string, the third an array, and the fourth one an object. Obviously, a file is a saved string data, so a JSON *file* would not be surrounded by quotes, like it is when we see JSON in code.

Thus,

```
cytoscape({
  ...
})
```

calls `cytoscape` with an object, not with a JSON. Were it to call it with JSON, it would have called it like this:

```
cytoscape('{ ... }')
```

JSON only supports a limited number of types; DOM elements are not among them. Meanwhile, you can stuff any JavaScript value into an object attribute:

```
var obj = {
  sum: 1 + 2,
  diff: 1 - 2
};
```

When this executes, `obj` will contain `sum: 3` and `diff: -1`. Similarly, when the object literal in the question is parsed, `container` attribute will contain a DOM element. JSON, not being executable, cannot have calls to JS functions.